# Android Studio Register and Login app [JAVA / PHP]

Tags: java, android

I followed and adapt a tutorial to create an application for register and login with databases and php.

The problem, I can't send POST request and the redirection didn't work. If I try 2 times, the application crash. I have try my PHP file with an HTML and it works perfectly so the problem is in the app.

Can you help me to solve this ?

RegisterActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.pandeo.loginapp.myrequest.MyRequest;

import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_send;
    private EditText et_email, et_password, et_password2;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private MyRequest request;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        et_password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password2);

        queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
        request = new MyRequest(this, queue);

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = et_email.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = et_password.getText().toString().trim();
                String password2 = et_password2.getText().toString().trim();
                if(email.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0 && password2.length() > 0) {
                    request.register(email, password, password2, new MyRequest.RegisterCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String message) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("REGISTER", message);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void inputErrors(Map<String, String> errors) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String message) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Veuillez remplir tous les champs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/register_title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password2"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password2"
                android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/register" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyRegister.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.pandeo.loginapp.LoginActivity;
import com.pandeo.loginapp.RegisterActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyRequest {

    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public MyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MyRequest(RegisterActivity registerActivity, RequestQueue queue) {
    }

    public MyRequest(LoginActivity loginActivity, RequestQueue queue) {
    }

    public void register(final String email, final String password, final String password2, final RegisterCallback callback){

        String url = "http://149.91.88.218/yolotest/register.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

                try{
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                    Boolean error = json.getBoolean("error");

                    if(!error){
                        callback.onSuccess("Vous êtes maintenant inscrit");

                    }else{
                        JSONObject messages = json.getJSONObject("message");
                        if(messages.has("email")){
                            errors.put("email", messages.getString("email"));
                        }
                        if(messages.has("password")){
                            errors.put("password", messages.getString("password"));
                        }

                        callback.inputErrors(errors);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if(error instanceof NetworkError){
                    callback.onError("Impossible de se connecter");
                }else if(error instanceof VolleyError){
                    callback.onError("Une erreur est survenue");
                }

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("email", email);
                map.put("password", password);
                map.put("password2", password2);

                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }

    public interface RegisterCallback{
        void onSuccess(String message);
        void inputErrors(Map<String, String> errors);
        void onError(String message);
    }
```

VolleySingleton.java

```
package com.pandeo.loginapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static Context ctx;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pandeo.loginapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

The initial tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC7p2zHbvXg

Thank's in advance.
Regards,
xxloubexx.

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? Can you post your log cast after debugging? How can we look at all that code ?

Comment: Hello, excuse me for the delay I can't reply before. The logs are too large so I put them into a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/rGEu0dfE

Comment: queue is null , that's why you are getting nullpointer , here  queue.add(request); you can't add something to a null object. Inialize queue or check if isn't null before doing  queue.add(request);